# Node: 'IteratorGetNext' - INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [5], [batch]: [0]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, transformer-model

I'm trying to work on the Kaggle Getting Started [Natural Language Processing with Disaster Tweets](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/nlp-getting-started) competition as an exam project for my uni deep learning course.

I am trying to solve the problem using a multi-input network, where the keyword and location columns are handled by two separate Conv1D networks, and the text column by a TransformerEncoder. I have the Conv1D networks working, but the TransformerEncoder is giving me the error in the title. I am using word embeddings (tried using both trained from scratch and with GloVe embeddings, but both give the same error) and positional encoding, and these are based on the [implementation](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/chapter11_part03_transformer.ipynb) (TransformerEncoder and PositionalEncoding classes) in the Chollet Deep Learning with Python, 2nd edition book.

This is how I process the dataset:

1. I import the .csv as a Pandas DataFrame and after some pre-processing, make a training and validation split
2. I convert the DataFrames into tf.data tensor datasets:

```
train_text = data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data['text'].values.astype(str), train_data['target'].values.astype(bool)))
train_keywords = data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data['keyword'].values.astype(str), train_data['target'].values.astype(bool)))
train_loc = data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data['location'].values.astype(str), train_data['target'].values.astype(bool)))

val_text = data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((validation_data['text'].values.astype(str), validation_data['target'].values.astype(bool)))
val_keywords = data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((validation_data['keyword'].values.astype(str), validation_data['target'].values.astype(bool)))
val_loc = data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((validation_data['location'].values.astype(str), validation_data['target'].values.astype(bool)))
```

I have also tried using methods that resemble the methods in [Load a pandas DataFrame](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe#a_dataframe_as_a_dictionary) more, but I got the same results.

3. I perform tokenization, standardization, and vectorization:

```
text_vectorization = TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=MAX_TOKENS_TEXT,
    output_sequence_length=max_text_length,
    standardize=standardize_text,
    output_mode='int'
)
keyword_vectorization = TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=MAX_TOKENS_KEYWORDS,
    output_sequence_length=MAX_KEYWORD_LENGTH,
    standardize=standardize_keywords,
    output_mode='int'
)
loc_vectorization = TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=MAX_TOKENS_KEYWORDS,
    output_sequence_length=MAX_LOC_LENGTH,
    standardize=standardize_loc,
    output_mode='int'
)

text_vectorization.adapt(train_text.map(lambda x, y: x))
keyword_vectorization.adapt(train_keywords.map(lambda x, y: x))
loc_vectorization.adapt(train_loc.map(lambda x, y: x))

train_text_vectorized = train_text.map(
    lambda x, y: (text_vectorization(x), y),
    num_parallel_calls=-1   # According to the documentation, -1 means auto
).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
train_loc_vectorized = train_loc.map(
    lambda x, y: (loc_vectorization(x), y),
    num_parallel_calls=-1
).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
train_keywords_vectorized = train_keywords.map(
    lambda x, y: (keyword_vectorization(x), y),
    num_parallel_calls=-1
).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

val_text_vectorized = val_text.map(
    lambda x, y: (text_vectorization(x), y),
    num_parallel_calls=-1
).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
val_loc_vectorized = val_loc.map(
    lambda x, y: (loc_vectorization(x), y),
    num_parallel_calls=-1
).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
val_keywords_vectorized = val_keywords.map(
    lambda x, y: (keyword_vectorization(x), y),
    num_parallel_calls=-1
).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Here, I have also tried the following, with the same result:

- Using a batch size of 1 instead of 32
- Not using .batch at all
- Using .padded_batch instead of .batch

4. Based on a recommendation [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16016#issuecomment-1312666517), I zip up the data into a format that the network will accept as input:

```
def dataset_zipper(loc, text, keyword):
    return (loc[0], text[0], keyword[0]), text[1]

train_full_vectorized = data.Dataset.zip((train_loc_vectorized, train_text_vectorized, train_keywords_vectorized))
train_full_vectorized = train_full_vectorized.map(dataset_zipper, num_parallel_calls=-1)

val_full_vectorized = data.Dataset.zip((val_loc_vectorized, val_text_vectorized, val_keywords_vectorized))
val_full_vectorized = val_full_vectorized.map(dataset_zipper, num_parallel_calls=-1)
```

Now I build the network:
1.

```
loc_input = Input(shape=(MAX_TOKENS_KEYWORDS,), dtype='int64', name='location')
keyword_input = Input(shape=(MAX_TOKENS_KEYWORDS,), dtype='int64', name='keyword')
text_input = Input(shape=(MAX_TOKENS_TEXT,), dtype="int64", name='text')

full_network = concatenate([
    generate_convnet(loc=True, input_layer=loc_input),
    generate_transformer(input_layer=text_input),
    generate_convnet(loc=False, input_layer=keyword_input)
])
full_network = Dropout(0.3)(full_network)
full_network = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(full_network)  # This is the classifier - since this is binary classification, I will use sigmoid activation
```

2. 

```
model = Model(inputs=[loc_input, text_input, keyword_input], outputs=full_network)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
```

3. 

```
callbacks = [
    ModelCheckpoint('twitter_disasters_v1.h5', save_best_only=True),
    EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, mode='min')]

results = model.fit(x=train_full_vectorized, validation_data=val_full_vectorized, class_weight=class_weights, callbacks=callbacks, epochs=100)
```

And here's where I get the error:

```
Node: 'IteratorGetNext'
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [5], [batch]: [0]
     [[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]
     [[gradient_tape/model_1/transformer_encoder_1/multi_head_attention_1/query/einsum/Einsum/_144]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [5], [batch]: [0]
     [[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_117129]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, should have just experimented more. Moving the .batch function from step 3 to step 4 (where I do the dataset zipping) and setting the batch size to 1 has worked and the network is now training, though I am open to better suggestions, if there are any.

Now I just have to solve the fact that loss is NaN...